# How to write a HQL query to get parent elements with child elements size in the where clause?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a parent entity say parent. A parent can have many childs. Now I want to write a HQL query to fetch all parents who have childs between say 5 to 10 i.e. basically between range.

Its basically a typical one to many relationship between parent and child.

Below is the parent entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent implements Serializable {

   /** The child list. */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentId")
    private List<Child> childList;
```

**Edit 1:**

OK so following is working

```
from parent p where p.childList.size >=2 and p.childList.size <=10
```

But now I also want to filter on one of the property of the child

like

```
from parent p where p.childList.size >=2 and p.childList.size <=10 and p.childList.age < 20
```

How do I do that in HQL?

Comment: Try "from Parent  p left join p.childList as child group by p.parent_id having count(child.child_id) between 5 and 10";

Comment: @anything Do you want to check age of each child?

Comment: @RAS, Yes. I want parents who have childs between certain range (say 2 to 3) where each child has certain age (say each child age is greater than 18).

Comment: @anything Why don't you use `criteria`?

Comment: @RAS Its existing query written in HQL with few other things so I just want to modify it

Comment: @anything Please see at edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Try join in HQL

```
select p from Parent p ,Child c where p.id=c.parent.id and c.age < 20 group by c.parent.id having count (c.parent.id) between 2 and 10
```

Comment: no its not working. its taking it as two separate filters. Size filter is still applied on all childs

Comment: Is that above hql query giving your expected result .